# PHP social contribution Yearly

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on a system report using PHP. I have a table with two columns (payment date and amount).

How I can use a while loop to calculate the total amount after each December through years? I tried to do it as per the screenshot attached but it displays the wrong sum after each December.

Below is how I did it:

```
 <?php 
    $total=0;
    $s = date('m');
    $c = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payroll_contribution_pssf WHERE employee_id='3' ORDER BY contribution_id ASC");
    while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($c))
    {
        $m = date('m', strtotime($array['payroll_date']));
        echo $array['payroll_date']." ".$array['employee_amount']."<br>";
        if($m==12)
        {
        if($total == 0)
        $total = $array['employee_amount'];
        $total = $total + $array['employee_amount'];
        echo number_format($total,0)."<br>";  
        }
    }
    
    
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't just show a screenshot and then talk about what you supposedly tried, but _show us_ what you actually did - code! [ask], [mre]

Comment: $total=0;
        $s = date('m');
        $c = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payroll_contribution_pssf WHERE employee_id='3' ORDER BY contribution_id ASC");
        while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($c))
        {
            $m = date('m', strtotime($array['payroll_date']));
            echo $array['payroll_date']." ".$array['employee_amount']."<br>";
            if($m==12)
            {
            if($total == 0)
            $total = $array['employee_amount'];
            $total = $total + $array['employee_amount']; echo number_format($total,0)."<br>";

Comment: Please don't show extended snippets of code in comments, that is hard to read. Edit our question & put it in there, properly formatted https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I have already updated the question. Sorry for the inconviniences

Comment: So, what result are you expecting instead? All you've told is that it's "wrong" in some unspecified way. We can't help you fix it if we don't know precisely what your requirement is.

Comment: However I'll guess that you want it to calculate and display the total value of all the previous rows since the last total (or since the start). In that case the flaw in your logic is that you're a) only adding the total from the current row and b) you're not resetting it. - you need to have a "total" variable which is incremented each time you loop, and also you need to reset it to 0 after displaying it.

Comment: Your logic to sum up the values makes little sense. For starters, you are _ignoring_ the values of all previous month, by having the whole "calculation" wrapped into `if($m==12) { ... }`

Comment: You need to sum up the values for _all_ months, no condition. And when you reached December, then you output the current total, and then reset $total to 0 again.

Comment: From the screenshot, I want to get the sum of the social contribution from July 2020 and then calculate the same from January 2021 to December 2021.  The values with the yellow line aside are wrong calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want it to calculate and display the total value of all the previous rows since the last total was calculated (or since the start of the dataset, in the case of the first iteration).

In that case the flaws in your logic are that you're

a) only adding to the total when it's the 12th month, and

b) you're not resetting it after you've reached the 12th month.

You need to have a "total" variable which is incremented each time you loop, and also you need to reset it to 0 after displaying it.

For example:

```
$total = 0;
$c = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payroll_contribution_pssf WHERE employee_id='3' ORDER BY contribution_id ASC");

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($c))
{
    $m = date('m', strtotime($array['payroll_date']));
    echo $array['payroll_date']." ".$array['employee_amount']."<br>";
    $total += $array['employee_amount']; //increment every time

    if ($m == 12)
    {
        echo number_format($total, 0)."<br>";
        $total = 0; //reset after displaying
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `$s` declared?  So basically, the OP needs to remove the `if($total == 0)` condition and add the `$total =0` after printing the yearly total?  I'm not sure that this question needs more focus.